# scala 2.8 implict java collections conversions

Tags: java, scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections, implicit-conversion

I have problem with JavaConversions with 2.8 beta:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
class Utils(dbFile : File, sep: String) extends IUtils {
    (...)
    def getFeatures() : java.util.List[String] =  csv.attributes.toList
}
```

And then exception:

```
[INFO]  Utils.scala:20: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : List[String]
[INFO]  required: java.util.List[String]
[INFO]   def getFeatures() : java.util.List[String] =  csv.attributes.toList
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 8):

`JavaConversions` does not support the conversion between a scala `List` (immutable, recursive data structure) and a java `List` (a mutable sequence). The analog in scala is a buffer:

From the [scaladoc](http://scaladocs.jcraft.com/2.8.0/)

> The following conversions are supported:
>      scala.collection.mutable.Buffer <=> java.util.List

You might want to change your code to:

```
def getFeatures() : java.util.List[String] 
    = new ListBuffer[String] ++ csv.attributes.toList
```